How to add specific org for jwt user in grafana?
I created user via Jwt payload =
payload =  {
  "sub": "ihor123",
  "name": "Ihor Doe",
  "email": "ihor123",
  "role": "Admin"
  }

auth.jwt:
enabled: true
header_name: X-JWT-Assertion
username_claim: user
email_claim: sub
username_attribute_path: user
email_attribute_path: sub
auto_sign_up: true
role_attribute_path: role
allow_assign_grafana_admin: true
url_login: true
key_file: /etc/grafana/keys/grafana.key.pub

Also when I try to log in via URL(localhost:3000?auth_token=xxxxx) all work, and my user was created by grafana. However, I could not provide a specific organization to the user "marketplace with org id 2" instead of the default "Main Org." I read this inf "The organization that the role is assigned to can be configured using the X-Grafana-Org-Id header." and tried to get it via curl but every time my user had default org. Can you explain to me how I can configure specific org for my jwt user? Thanks
i tried to use curl with header 'X-Grafana-Org-Id', wrote orgid into jwt, wrote orgid into url 0 result
